# True Minus Sign On X-axis Variable Labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to get a true minus sign into a graph in ggplot2.

Generate data:

```
score <- c(rnorm(8, 20, 3), rnorm(8, 35, 5))
gene <- factor((rep(c(1,2), each = 8)))
df <- data.frame(gene, score)
```

Now rename factor with a name that includes a minus sign

```
require(plyr)

df$gene <- mapvalues(df$gene, from = c(1,2), to = c("Gene -", "Gene +"))
```

Now graph the dataframe in ggplot2

```
cellMeansDF <- aggregate(score ~ gene, df, mean)

require(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(cellMeansDF, aes(gene, score)) +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", size = 0.1) + 
         xlab("") + 
         theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "plain", color = "black", size = 15))

plot1
```

Now notice the minus sign is not wide enough. It is really a dash. How do I get ggplot2 to display a true minus sign? Even an en dash would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Unicode *en dash* character instead of a hyphen:

```
"Gene \u2013"
```

Which gives:

```
"Gene –"
```

Whereas the standard hyphen looks like this:

```
"Gene -"
```

So, change the hyphen to an en dash in your code:

```
df$gene <- mapvalues(df$gene, from = c(1,2), to = c("Gene \u2013", "Gene +"))
```

To get the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Yep. Exactly what i needed and very neat.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You can of course take or leave the bold according to your preference.

```
score <- c(rnorm(8, 20, 3), rnorm(8, 35, 5))
gene <- factor((rep(c(1,2), each = 8)))
df <- data.frame(gene, score)


require(plyr)

df$gene <- mapvalues(df$gene, from = c(1,2), to = c("Gene -", "Gene +"))

Now graph the dataframe in ggplot2

cellMeansDF <- aggregate(score ~ gene, df, mean)

require(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(cellMeansDF, aes(gene, score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", size = 0.1) + 
  xlab("") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family="mono", face="bold", color = "black", size = 15))

plot1
```

[image: Plot]

You can find a complete list of fonts here: 
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Fonts/

The font and other `element_text` options will determine how this character displays. Here's a graphic summary of your font choices:

[image: Fonts]

Comment: Thankyou very much @Hack-R for the exemplar of font types, but I don't think changing the font will do it in this case. Especially since it will involve the abscissa labels being a different font to the rest.