# True negative sign in continuous y-axis scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

Owing to the journal's formatting requirement, I need to use a true negative sign (UTF-16: 2212) for my graphs. This is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077931/r-how-to-use-proper-minus-symbol-for-negative-axes-in-plot), except that my existing plots are based on ggplot. Rather than reconfiguring them back to base R plot, I am hoping to find a ggplot2-native solution.

The current ggplot-based questions here unfortunately deal with [text annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059399/how-do-i-write-value-plus-minus-sign-value-along-with-text-with-anno), [character axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931258/true-minus-sign-on-x-axis-variable-labels-in-ggplot2), or [headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495784/displaying-true-minus-sign-in-ggplot2-bar-graph-embedded-in-rmarkdown-document) instead of continuous axis ticks. Meanwhile, the closest idea I have for the scale_y_continuous function is to use the [label variable in the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699601/using-parentheses-for-negative-values-on-y-axis-ggplot2) or simply use break and [manually tune all the relevant axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794265/changing-x-axis-ticks-in-ggplot2), but I am still figuring it out.

The manual way for now:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = -3:3, labels = c("\U2212\U0033","\U2212\U0032","\U2212\U0031",0,1,2,3))
```

This produces a plot with the default hyphen-minus sign on the y-axis and the true minus sign on the x-axis. However, the number has to be coded in UTF format, else it could be concatenated by the UTF reader into another UTF character (i.e. "\U22123" is a Chinese character instead of -3.)

[image]

May I ask if there is a more elegant and/or dynamic solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own labeller function.

```r
library(ggplot2)

label_trueminus <- function(x){
  ifelse(sign(x) == -1, paste0("\u2212", abs(x)), x)
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg-20, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_trueminus)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Excellent, simple solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

or even shorter:

```
library(tidyverse)

label_parse <- function(breaks) {
  parse(text = breaks)
}

# sample data
tibble(
  a = -5:5,
  b = rnorm(length(a))
) %>% 
  # sample plotting
  ggplot(aes(a,b)) +
  geom_point() +
  # here's the magic
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_parse)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it worked too. Unfortunately someone else had a more parsimonous answer. :)

Comment: interesting +1. The minus sign seems weirdly slightly offset at least in my device. Any idea why this might be happening?